# Using handlebars to return specific <ul><li> tags within JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

I have the following JSON Object in my javascript:

```
var source = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var igListOrig = [
  {
    "IG":"Problem Solving", 
    "AIR_Indicators": "All Domain 1 Indicators* 3.1, 3.2, 3.3,     3.4", 
    "SMP": "SMP 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8", 
    "Purpose": "Students must be able to reason, problem solve, communicate and make real life       decisions that require mathematical thinking.  Teaching students problem solving skills and giving them opportunities to apply their skills is critical to developing their capacity to solve mathematical problems that arise in all our lives (e.g. starting a small business, figuring out the area of a room in order to purchase the correct amount of paint, filling out a tax return, tracking and setting goals for investments, etc.)", 
    "IP":"Problem of the Week(PoW)", 
    "What": "PoWs are omplex problems that students solve and then explain their solutions and reasoning in a write up.  More weight should be given to mathematical thinking and a good write up than finding the correct solution.",
    "When": "PoWs should be administered once per month.  Students should work on problem the first 10-15 minutes of a period for 5-7 consecutive days.", 
    "How": "1.Introduce problem, process, and rubric. 2.Students are given time in class to work on problem throughout the week. 3.Students complete write up. 4.Student peer edit write up. 5.Students revise write up"
  },

  {
    "IG":"Problem Solving", 
    "AIR_Indicators": "All Domain 1 Indicators* 3.1, 3.2, 3.3,     3.4", 
    "SMP": "SMP 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8", 
    "Purpose": "Students must be able to reason, problem solve, communicate and make real life       decisions that require mathematical thinking.  Teaching students problem solving skills and giving them opportunities to apply their skills is critical to developing their capacity to solve mathematical problems that arise in all our lives (e.g. starting a small business, figuring out the area of a room in order to purchase the correct amount of paint, filling out a tax return, tracking and setting goals for investments, etc.)", 
    "IP":"Problem of the Week(PoW)", 
    "What": "PoWs are omplex problems that students solve and then explain their solutions and reasoning in a write up.  More weight should be given to mathematical thinking and a good write up than finding the correct solution.",
    "When": "PoWs should be administered once per month.  Students should work on problem the first 10-15 minutes of a period for 5-7 consecutive days.", 
    "How": "1.Introduce problem, process, and rubric. 2.Students are given time in class to work on problem throughout the week. 3.Students complete write up. 4.Student peer edit write up. 5.Students revise write up"
  }

]

$('body').append(template(igListOrig));
```

How do I use Handlebar helpers to print `igListOrig.[0].How` in an `<ul><li>` tags?

Here's the html where I want it placed

```
<div class="bottom-container text">
    <div class="cube">
      <h4>Instructional Practice</h4>
      <center><h3> {{IP}} </h3> </center> </br>
      <p><span class="description">What</span> {{What}} </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">When</span> {{When}} </p></br>
      <p><span class="description">How</span> {{How}} </p></br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the JS Fiddle for a full example http://jsfiddle.net/rr9Vz/

Comment: Im not totally clear what you are looking for, but if you want numbered output you would need to convert ".How" to an array first.So it looks like this... `["Introduce problem, process, and rubric.","Students are given..."]`

Comment: Ah yes, but how do I do this and pass it into a handle bars template.  I can't change the JSON object as it's coming through a different source.

Comment: Once you have a decoded JSON object its a "pojo". You can do stuff to it. You can loop through the items in the pojo and run a regex pattern against it e.g. `.How'.split(/{0-9}\./)`